# Size method with imposed prototype c++

Tags: c++

I have some issue while writing the following function :

```
static int taille(const PElement<T> * l)
```

That's how our teacher tell us to write that function which return the size ( the word 'taille' means size in french ).

So I thought about declaring a pointer on a PElement in the function. And do the following :

```
static int taille( PElement<T> * l)
{
    int somme;
    PElement<T> * it = new PElement<T>(null, null);
    it = l;
    for (somme = 0; it != null; it = it->s)
    {
        somme++;
    }
    return somme;
}
```

That code is working but you have noticed that I removed the const keyword for the parameter (PElement * l) in the function header.

Could someone try to explain to me how write that function with the const keyword ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to leak memory, so remove the `new` line. Just iterate over `l` instead of `it`.

Comment: With `const` in place, he will not be able to *Just iterate over `l` instead of `it`*.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs And why not?

Comment: @juanchopanza, because assigning a value to const l will generate an error during compilation, or?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Why would it? The parameter is pointer to const object, not const pointer.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs: It's the `PElement` being pointed to, not the pointer, that's constant. A constant pointer would be `T * const`.

Comment: Thanks to your comments. It helped a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly the same, except the local pointer would have to have the same type. Also, don't allocate an element just to reassign the pointer and leak it.

```
const PElement<T> * it = l;
```

Of course, there's not much point declaring a new variable just to hold the value of the parameter. Just use the parameter directly:

```
for (somme = 0; l; l = l->s)
```

Note that `null` isn't a standard way to specify a null pointer. Use `nullptr` in C++11 or later, `NULL` or `0` in historic dialects, or just use the pointer in a boolean context as I did.

Comment: What ? Oh my... It works perfectly, but I can't get it. The parameter l is const right ? So how is it possible to change its value and iterate over ?

Comment: @Indray: No, it's a non-constant pointer to a constant `PElement`. If the pointer itself were const, it would be `PElement<T> * const l`. In general `const` qualifies the thing to its left (with an exception if there's nothing to the left).